# How can I prevent focus stealing in Windows?

Tags: windows, user-interface, focus-stealing

A quick Google search for solutions to [Focus Stealing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Focus_stealing) in Windows reveals two main result categories:

- People suggesting incomplete solutions involving the
  ForegroundLockTimeout registry entry (or TweakUI, which I believe simply changes the aforementioned registry entry),
  which isn't very effective.
- [Incessant](http://www.windows7taskforce.com/view/3681) [hordes](http://www.vistaheads.com/forums/microsoft-public-windows-vista-administration-accounts-passwords/52293-stealing-focus.html) of Windows users [complaining](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/please-dont-steal-my-focus.html) about [it](http://www.dslreports.com/forum/r20852170-Vista-Stop-stealing-focus).

It's particularly annoying in two common scenarios:

- Something triggers a program to popup a dialog window in the background while a fullscreen app is focused, causing the fullscreen app to minimize.
- A window steals focus while you are typing, stealing all of your keystrokes. If you happen to press Space, Enter, or trigger a keyboard shortcut (like Y for Yes), it can cause completely undesirable outcomes.

What creative solutions can be applied to fix this problem for either or both of these scenarios?

Comment: The programming solution would be to write apps that don't steal focus, which doesn't seem to be what's being asked here.  I think this is a job for Super User.

Comment: Super User failed to deliver on this exact issue. http://superuser.com/questions/18383/preventing-applications-stealing-focus - their only solution was the aforementioned broken ForegroundLockTimeout/TweakUI answer

Comment: I'm going to attempt a solution for the keystroke half of the problem. I wouldn't know where to begin to universally fix fullscreen apps unfocusing.

Answer (score 2):

I have one suggestion for how it can be solved, but I cannot implement it completely since I lack the knowledge.

The focus change between windows have to be instigated by the offending program calling a Windows API function located most probably in shell32 or user32. Some progams, like Adobe Photoshop makes the call multiple times (at least twice) to force itself up on the user when it's starting. The idea is to hook into this API function (if possible) and check where the call originates from. If it's not from *explorer.exe* (i.e. Alt+Tabbing or clicking an icon on the taskbar), then call should be blocked by said hook.

Comment: I found an API windows uses to notify programs when other programs gain focus (like for shells to display the active window). I believe it can be used to completely prevent the focus event from happening.